# my sql is reurning row with null value

Tags: mysql

I am using following my sql query...

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.description, p.game, p.icon, p.comments_allowed, p.views, p.dnt, u.id AS poster_id, 
u.username AS posted_by, u.icon AS poster_icon, COUNT(c.id) AS total_comments 
    FROM ne_posts p 
        LEFT JOIN ne_users u 
            ON u.id = p.posted_by 
        LEFT JOIN ne_comments c 
            ON c.id = p.id 
    WHERE p.game = "game1" LIMIT 4
```

but there are not any row for game1 in posts table, but its still returning row with all values as NULL. What's am i doing wrong? please help, thanks.

Comment: Where is your `GROUP BY` clause? you have an aggregate function in that.

Comment: do you mean to say, i should add `GROUP_BY p.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an aggregate function (COUNT) with no GROUP BY clause on the query.

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.description, p.game, p.icon, p.comments_allowed, p.views, p.dnt, u.id AS poster_id, 
u.username AS posted_by, u.icon AS poster_icon, COUNT(c.id) AS total_comments 
    FROM ne_posts p 
        LEFT JOIN ne_users u 
            ON u.id = p.posted_by 
        LEFT JOIN ne_comments c 
            ON c.id = p.id 
    WHERE p.game = "game1" 
    GROUP BY p.id, p.title, p.description, p.game, p.icon, p.comments_allowed, p.views, p.dnt, u.id, u.username, u.icon
    LIMIT 4
```